# Justification of Halmos' proof of all the bases of a finite-dimensional vector space must have the same number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having difficulties in understanding the proof for the following theorem which is stated in section 1.8 of Paul Halmos' *Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*:

**Theorem.** The number of elements in any basis of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is the same as in any other basis.

**Proof.** For the proof, he used another theorem which is stated in section 1.6 which I mention below:

**Theorem 1.6.** The set of non-zero vectors $x_1, ..., x_n$ is linearly dependent if and only if some $x_k, 2 \leqq k \leqq n$ is a linear combination of the preceding ones.

Let's continue with the proof of the theorem. Let $X=\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ and $Y = \{y_1, ..., y_m\}$ be two finite sets of vectors, each with one of the two defining properties of a basis; i.e., we assume that every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the $x$'s (but not that the $x$'s are linearly independent), and we assume that the $y$'s are linearly independent (but not that every vector is a linear combination of them). We form the set $S$ like this:
$$S = \{y_m, x_1, ..., x_n\}$$
every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of elements of $S$ (by definition of $X$) and $S$ is linearly dependent (I assume this is due to $X$'s property again). So, we can apply the theorem 1.6 to this set; hence, one of $x$'s should be a linear combination of its preceding vectors. (It cannot be $y_m$ since $k$ must be in range $[2, n]$ by theorem 1.6). Let's denote that vector by $x_i$, then we can form the set $S^\prime$ like this:
$$S^\prime = \{y_m, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n\}$$
Again, every vector in $V$ is a linear combination of the set $S^\prime$ since by $\{y_m, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}\}$ we can generate $x_i$ and by $x$'s we can express all the vectors in $V$, i.e., span $V$.

Then Halmos continued by adding $y_{m-1}$ in front of the vectors of $S^\prime$ and formed $S^{\prime\prime}$:
$$S^{\prime\prime} = \{y_{m-1}, y_m, x_1, ..., x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n\}$$
Them he stated that we "apply the same argument" meaning that we can delete one more element of $S^{\prime\prime}$. That element cannot be one of the $y$'s since they are linearly independent by the definition. So, it must be one of the $x$'s again. **But, my question is why $S^{\prime\prime}$ is linearly dependent?** Is it due to the addition of $y_{m-1}$? Because $x$'s can span $V$ and $y_{m-1}$ is a vector in $V$; hence, $S^{\prime\prime}$ is linearly dependent. Is this correct?

If my assumption is correct, what can we tell about the set $S^\prime$ in terms of linear dependence/independence? As mentioned before, $S^\prime$ can span $V$ including $y_m$, but since $y_m$ is used to produce $x_i$, and then $X$ (including $x_i$) can be used to produce $y_m$, we can't use this argument to prove that $S^\prime$ is linearly dependent. So, probably we can't make any assumptions about the linear dependency of $S^\prime$. Is this conclusion correct as well?

Comment: $S'$ is a spanning set of $V$ and it is a proper subset of $S''$. Hence $S''$ is linearly dependent.